# Как загрузить изображения через js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Есть `html` приложение которое написано на `js` (Без использования серверных языков) Нужно как-то через `js` по `url` сохранить картинки, чтобы приложение могло их использовать в офлайновом режиме.

Пытался решить проблему прогоном в `base64` и хранением изображения в `localStorage`. Этот способ работает, но с одной оговоркой, для запроса нужно разрешить это действие:

```
 <?php
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 ?>
```

Проблема в том, что у меня нет доступа к сайту, с которого я хочу брать картинки. Можно ли как-то устранить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Только клиентскими средствами никак нельзя, безопасность браузеров не позволяет так сохранять данные, в любом случае необходимо работать через серверные языки. 
Сохранять картинки по URL можно только если парсить страницу нужного вам сайта, например через php, и уже потом правда им же сохранять в свою базу данных на своем сервере.

Comment: Допустим. Но как данные именно картинки вы предполагаете сохранять, что бы это был не просто файл с разрешением, а именно картинка? Вы же сами указываете , что нужен header. Я по крайней мере не знаю способов без использования серверной стороны.